# Links inside Jscrollpane not Clickable in Safari and Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, hyperlink, jscrollpane

I am having a problem with links inside a jscrollpane in Safari and Chrome on Windows. The links are typical backlinks using java:history.back() and are placed inside a jquery jscrollpane. The page can be seen here:

http://www.roman-bold-black.com/index.php?id=24

When trying to click the link nothing happens, and there is no change in the mouse cursor appearance when placed over the link.

The problem only occurs in Safari and Chrome, works fine in FF.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that

```
<h1>AFA</h1>
```

is covering the link.

You'll probably have to set a width, like this:

```
<h1 style="width: 200px;">AFA</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to give it another z-index? The "zurück" link seems to be behind the div with the text "AFA".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved it invoking `reinitialise()` every time the content inside jscroll pane changes (eg. adding elements inside).